# git ftp init not working for initial commit

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have following lines in my Bitbucket pipeline

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
  custom: # Pipelines that are triggered manually via the Bitbucket GUI
    init: # -- First time init
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp init -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" ftp://$FTP_HOST

    deploy-all: # -- Deploys all files from the selected commit
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp push -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" ftp://$FTP_HOST --all
```

For some reason I am getting error while this pipeline runs.

This is the error I am getting.

```
+ git ftp push -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" ftp://$FTP_HOST --force
fatal: Could not get last commit. Network down? Wrong URL? Use 'git ftp init' for the initial push., exiting...
```

Can anybody help me what I did wrong?

Comment: Is this a public repo? If not, then why are you using an insecure protocol like FTP instead of something like SFTP or FTPS?

Comment: @Jim Redmond can you help me solve me this issue. I am completely new to this pipeline. I am having this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason somebody deleted the .git-ftp.log file from the server.

So, I re-initialize git-ftp.log file again.

Steps:

1. go to the "Commits" page in your bitbucket repository.
2. Choose the latest commit, then on the right hand side of that page you'll find a "Run pipeline" link with which you can manually trigger pipelines.
3. Select "custom: init" and wait until the pipeline is finished.